# TabSpec with ListActivity … how to set OnClickListener for Button?

Tags: android, android-layout, casting, android-listview

In a TabHost, I'm setting up a TabSpec that consists of a header area with a few buttons and below, a ListView. The Activity to manage this TabSpec is defined as "extends ListActivity".
However, now I'm running into the problem of not being able to define an OnClickListener to check for the submit button pressed. How can I solve that?

Trying to cast the Button by

```
btnRatingSubmit.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

raises an ClassCastException...

Here is a basic excerpt of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edComment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnSubmit" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
btnRatingSubmit.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

try this:

```
btnRatingSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It should not be a problem, if you `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);` and get the instance of `btnSubmit`. But if you are facing the problem so better just change your `ListActivity` to `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with ((OnClickListener) this). I can't exacly tell what is wrong without more code on this class. But, are you implementing OnClickListener on the Activity which holds this button? Otherwise, try casting like this ((View.OnClickListener) this).

Answer (score 0):

You should either implement View.OnClickListener for the activity to continue using (OnClickListener) this, or simply create a new View.OnClickListener to replace "this"